# How to pass function between multiple components in React Native

Tags: react-native, function, components

I have problem and I didnt find answer, so I try anyone who could help with:

I have main app component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {...}

openSettings = () => { ....some changing state}

render(){
return (...
<Settings openSettings={() =>this.openSettings()}/>
      );}
...};
```

My Settings file :

```
const Settings = ({openSetting}) => {
    return (
      <MyHeader openSetting={openSetting}></MyHeader>...
    )}
export default Settings;
```

And I want to pass openSetting to another file:

```
const MyHeader = ({openSetting}) => {
    return (
      <Text onPress={openSetting}>Open it!</Text>
    )}
export default MyHeader ;
```

Anyone knows why it doesnt work?

Comment: Cannot understand your question, do you mean you want to pass the function "openSettings" to multiple components in different files ?

Comment: See the code above, I want to pass openSetting from Settings to MyHeader as onPress action. Settings and MyHeader are in diferrent files.

Comment: As I can see you're passing the function correctly between the components. What error are you having? Please provide more details

Comment: It works between "main app" and "settings". But I need this flow: App -> Settings ->MyHeader (It does nothing)

Comment: Your flow is exactly what you are saying you want, its from App -> Settings -> MyHeader. Its correctly flowing inside the components ? are we missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably the typo on your code thats causing this issue, and its not working.

You created a function named openSettings, but you sent the props as openSetting. Try writing the prop name correctly without typo and it should work.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {...}

openSettings = () => { ....some changing state}

render(){
return (...
<Settings openSettings={() =>this.openSettings()}/> //<== Check this line
      );}
...};

const Settings = ({openSettings}) => { //<== Check this line
    return (
      <MyHeader openSettings={openSettings}></MyHeader>... //<== Check this line
    )}
export default Settings;


const MyHeader = ({openSettings}) => { //<== Check this line
    return (
      <Text onPress={openSettings}>Open it!</Text> //<== Check this line
    )}
export default MyHeader ;
```

Comment: You right, it works - bad typo "openSettings" vs "openSetting". Sorry for that and thank you for your time.